# Dealing with model save and update with GWT Platform

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

I'm trying to adapt my GWT web application from my home-grown MVC to [GWT Platform](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/).

I've managed to port the my application views with presenters, and essentially able to access views via PlaceRequest. And with changing the URL (#).

However I am not sure how to deal with Models using this GWT platform, in the common MVP I know there is a go() method in the presenter which fetches data, say from server via RPC.

In the GWT platform presenter here are the methods automatically generated by the Eclipse plugin:

- Constructor
- revealInParent
- onBind
- onReset

Where should I put the RPC code that will fetch and update my model. Say in the presenter I have:

ProfilePresenter.java:

```
public class ProfilePresenter
        extends
        Presenter<ProfilePresenter.MyView, ProfilePresenter.MyProxy> {

    public interface MyView extends View {
        HasText getFullname();
        HasText getLocation();
        HasText getAboutme();
        HasText getLastlogin();
    }

    private User user; // Model which represents the User information etc.
```

And when the View associated with the Presenter is shown I need to fetch the User model from the server and update the model and then subsequently update the view through the interfaces it expose.

Also, say I have some buttons in the view, which then can be accessed by the presenter through `HasClickHandler` where should I put the event handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sydney covered most of your questions.

In general `onReset`method is a good place to make backend calls.
Sometimes when the backend call takes longer and you want to display the view only after the data was loaded you can use [manual reveal](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted?tm=6#Using_manual_reveal).
But for the profile page I don't think that is necessary.

I also agree with the reverse MVP pattern. It's way easer to test presenters using the reverse MVP Pattern than using the `HasXXXHandlers` interfaces.

Comment: Actually you are right, I mean the main reason I want to use GWTP now is that my application RPC really takes time to be fetched. I mean, its data is coming from several RPC calls making the UI show blank fields at some point in time. This is the main problem with my home grown MVC.

Answer (score 2):

I would put the RPC call in the `onReset` method. 
[See the presenter lifecycle](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted#Presenter_lifecycle)

Personally I deal with events using the [reversed MVP pattern](http://arcbees.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/reversing-the-mvp-pattern-and-using-uihandler/). But you can also call a handler this way:

```
    getView().getSubmitButton().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        }
    });
```

with the following signature for `getSubmitButton` in your view interface:

```
HasClickHandlers getSubmitButton()
```